# get_pages() as per custom menu order

Tags: pages, menu-order

I'm working on Single Page WordPress Theme where I want to get_pages() as per custom menu order.

I have gone through the reference for [get_pages()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) which only allows for default menu :

```
get_pages('sort_order=asc&sort_column=menu_order');
```

Is there any way to get_pages() as per **custom menu order** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have Found My Own Solution. 
I Tried To Get Page ID Of Each Custom Menu Item & Rendered Page Based On That ID.

Reference : [wp get nav menu items](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items)

Like This...

```
    $menu_name = 'primary-menu';

    if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ) {
            $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
            $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
            foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
                $qcPageID = $menu_item->object_id;
                $qcPageData = get_page( $qcPageID );
            }
    }
```